# How to display JSON data from Horizontal recycle view kotlin using MVP method

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope is all well with you.

I have constructed my code and build according the MVP style as well pulling JSON data but when I run the the code the horizontal recycle view and the JSON data is not being displayed. I tried going through every line of code and watching other tutorials but still no results.

Here is below my main activity:

```
    class ProductCategoryActivity : BaseMvpActivity<ProductCategoryActivityView, ProductCategoryActivityPresnter> (),
    ProductCategoryActivityView, CategoryAdapter.onItemClickListener{


    private  lateinit var binding: FragmentProductCategoryBinding
    val data :MutableList<CateogryResponse> = ArrayList()
    val adapter= CategoryAdapter(data, this)
    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: ProductCategoryActivityPresnter

    @Inject
    lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

    override fun onCreateComponent() {
        userComponent.plus(CategoryActivityModule(this)).inject(this)
    }

    override fun providePresenter(): ProductCategoryActivityPresnter {
        return presenter
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentProductCategoryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        presenter.fetchcatogries()
        showdata(ArrayList())

    }

    override fun showError(message: String) {

    }

    override fun showProgress() {

    }

    override fun hideProgress() {

    }


    override fun showdata(data: ArrayList<CateogryResponse>) {

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerViewPrimary.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerViewPrimary.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerViewPrimary.adapter = adapter

        for(i in data)
          data.add(CateogryResponse("product"))


    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item $position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val clickedItem = data[position]
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

}
```

Here is my presenter:

```
@ActivityScope

class ProductCategoryActivityPresnter @Inject constructor(
    private val stringProvider: StringProvider,
    @AndroidScheduler private val observeOnScheduler: Scheduler,
    @IOScheduler private val subscribeOnScheduler: Scheduler,
    private val getCategoryUseCase: CategoryUseCase


) : BasePresenter<ProductCategoryActivityView>() {

    lateinit var catogriesservice: CategoryRepositoryImpl
    val catogriesLoadError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var catogries: ArrayList<CateogryResponse> = arrayListOf()
    override fun onCreatePresenter(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    }

    override fun onLoadData(arguments: Bundle?) {
        fetchcatogries()
    }

    fun fetchcatogries() {
        getCategoryUseCase.execute()
            .observeOn(observeOnScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler)
            .subscribe(
                SingleRequestSubscriber(
                    {
                        it
                        if (it != null && it.size > 0) {
                            catogries.removeAll(catogries)
                            catogries.addAll(it)
                        }
                    },
                    onFailure = { appException ->
                        view?.showError(
                            ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(
                                appException,
                                stringProvider
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    onApiError = { apiException ->
                        view?.showError(
                            ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(
                                apiException,
                                stringProvider
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    onAuthenticationError = { requestxception ->
                        view?.showError(
                            ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(
                                requestxception,
                                stringProvider
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    onShowProgress = {
                        if (it) {
                            view?.showProgress()
                        } else {
                            view?.hideProgress()
                        }
                    },
                    onSubscribed = {
                        disposable.add(it)
                    })
            )
    }


}
```

Here is my view:

```
interface ProductCategoryActivityView {
    fun showError(message: String)
    fun showProgress()
    fun hideProgress()
    fun showdata ( data: ArrayList<CateogryResponse>)


}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
class CategoryAdapter(
    private val data: List<CateogryResponse>,
    private val listener: onItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val items: MutableList<CardView>

    init {
        this.items = ArrayList()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_adapter, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tvTitle.text = data[position].product

        items.add(holder.card)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

     inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
   View.OnClickListener {

         val tvTitle: TextView = itemView.featured_title
         val card: CardView = itemView.CardView

         init {
             itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
         }

         override fun onClick(v: View?) {

             val position: Int = adapterPosition
             if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                 listener.onItemClick(position)
             }
         }
     }
    interface onItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)

    }


}
```

Image:

[image]

Fragment Category Adapter:

```
    android:id="@+id/CardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <!-- We Will Add here the card & ImageViews -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featured_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/featured_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineHeight="23dp"
            android:text="Chairs"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/featured_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="asbkd asudhlasn saudnas jasdjasl hisajdl asjdlnas" />


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Fragment Product Category:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fafcfe"
    tools:context="ui.category.ProductCategoryActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/topselling"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSecondary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCategories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/catogries"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Not sure what went wrong.
If someone can point it out or show me what needs to be done to be able to display the data in horzintal recycle view, I would be really thanlful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your recycler view adapter once your fetch call is executed, not before it ends.
Modify your `fetchcatogries` declaration so it accepts a callback method, which will be executed after the data are loaded.
This method will accept a list object as a parameter, which you will manage in your `ProductCategoryActivity` to populate the `RecyclerView`.

```
fun fetchcatogries(callback: (MutableList<CateogryResponse>) -> Unit) {
    getCategoryUseCase.execute()
            .observeOn(observeOnScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler)
            .subscribe(
                SingleRequestSubscriber(
                    { categories -> 
                        callback(categories)
                    },
                    ...
            )
}
```

You can now edit your `onCreate` and `showdata` methods in `ProductCategoryActivity` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentProductCategoryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    presenter.fetchcatogries { categories -> 
        showdata(categories as ArrayList<CateogryResponse>)
    }
}

override fun showdata(data: ArrayList<CateogryResponse>) {
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    recyclerViewPrimary.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerViewPrimary.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerViewPrimary.adapter = CategoryAdapter(data.toList(), this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Really thankful for your time. 
I am getting an error at: showdata(categories.toTypedArray()) 
Error type: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:  
How to fix this error ? Could the error be because CategoryReponse is JSON data ?

Comment: There was a mistake with typecasting, it was converting the mutable list to an array instead of an array list. Check the edited answer for the correct cast.

Comment: Thank you so much 
I just ran the app and still I am having the issue it is not displaying the horizontal recycle view. I Have edited my question and post the image and the fragments

Comment: Could it be possible the way I am loading my data fetchcatogries . override fun onLoadData(arguments: Bundle?) {
        fetchcatogries {  }
    }

Comment: I think that the problem is in your XML layout, you should set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your `recyclerViewPrimary`.

Comment: My recyclerViewPrimary has this error: 
This view is not constrained vertically: at runtime it will jump to the top unless you add a vertical constraint 
Could this be the cause ? Anyway, I fixed the issue and did what you told me. 
Still it is not displayed. This is driving me crazy but again thank for your time. If there is any tips you can provide ?

Comment: I fixed the issue and got the data back. It was in Android manifest.